# Calculate limit $\lim_{x \to 2} \frac{(2^x)-4}{\sin(\pi x)}$ without L'Hopital's rule

Tags: limits-without-lhopital

How to calculate limit: $\lim_{x \to 2} \frac{(2^x)-4}{\sin(\pi x)}$ without L'Hopital's rule?

If $x = 2$, I get uncertainty $\frac{0}{0}$

Comment: Hints: $b^x = e^{\ln(b) x}$ and $\lim_{x \rightarrow 0} \frac{e^x - 1}{x} = 1$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$\lim_{x \to 2} \frac{(2^x)-4}{\sin(\pi x)}
$

Putting $x = y+2$,

$\begin{array}\\
\dfrac{(2^x)-4}{\sin(\pi x)}
&=\dfrac{(2^{y+2})-4}{\sin(\pi (y+2))}\\
&=4\dfrac{(2^{y})-1}{\sin(\pi y)}
\qquad\text{since } 2^{y+2} = 4\cdot 2^y
 \text{ and }\sin(\pi (y+2))=\sin(\pi y + 2\pi)=\sin(\pi y)\\
&=4\dfrac{e^{y\ln 2}-1}{\sin(\pi y)}\\
&\approx 4\dfrac{y\ln 2}{\pi y}
\qquad\text{since } e^z \approx 1+z \text{ and } \sin(z) \approx z
\text{ for small }z\\
&= \dfrac{4\ln 2}{\pi }
\end{array}
$

Comment: Why $\sin(\pi (y+2)) / 4 = \sin(\pi y) $?

Comment: Because $\sin(z+2\pi) = \sin(z)$ for all $z$. The 4 doesn't come into this part.

Comment: Trigonometric formulas, sorry, I not right away understand it.

Comment: What is the symbol $\approx$.

Comment: Approximately equal to.

Comment: Help: why $e^{y\ln(2)}-1=y\ln(2)$?

Comment: $e^z \approx 1+z$ - how is called this formula?

Comment: This is the first two terms of the power series approximation to $e^z$ around $z=0$.

Answer (score 2):

Put $x=t+2$ and compute

$$4\lim_{t\to 0}\frac{e^{t\ln(2)}-1}{\sin(\pi t)}$$

$$=\frac{4\ln(2)}{\pi}\lim_{t\to 0}\frac{e^{t\ln(2)-1}}{t\ln(2)}\frac{\pi t}{\sin(\pi t)}$$

$$=\frac{4\ln(2)}{\pi}.$$

Comment: @Fatima, you are right, but I do not understand the solution progress :(

Comment: @divisor What didn't you uderstdand.

Answer (score 1):

**HINT:**

$$\frac{2^x-4}{\sin(\pi x)}=\left(\frac{2^x-4}{x-2}\right)\,\left(\frac{x-2}{\sin(\pi (x-2))}\right) \tag 1$$

The limit of the first parenthetical term in $(1)$ is the derivative of $2^x$ at $x=2$.  And $\lim_{\theta \to 0}\frac{\sin(\theta)}{\theta}=1$.

Comment: Please let me know how I can improve my answer.  I really want to give you the best answer I can.  And Happy Holidays!  -Mark

Comment: The problem is that your answer is difficult for me. I upvote your answer. I also try to explore your other answers in gratitude for your time, and upvote their too. Thank you and Happy Holidays :)